# 119, 019, 609, 809, ?, 909 - A number sequence

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

> 119, 019, 609, 809, xxx, 909

What is the underlying principle here?

Source: 2.2., 4, https://www.helsinki.fi/sites/default/files/atoms/files/psykologia_valintakoe_2019.pdf

Answer (score 6):

The answer is:

> **L09**

You might think I have made a mistake there, but I suggest that you:

> consider what all of the terms of your sequence look like when written on a calculator (or similar 7-segment display) and turned upside down!

Try it yourself and see!

Comment: Classic parking place puzzle. Upvote.